# PDF cannot be saved in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, pdf

I try to open pdf in embed html element.

In chrome it opens as `<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,%base64pdfstring%" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="140">`
and it does not give me to save pdf file.

In firefox it opens ok and save operation can be done.

Printing feature works wrong as well. It does not save paper size and resets as default paper size in print dialog, so as a result - ruins all the layout.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may create the link with inline base64 content that will ask user to download the content by setting the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) HTML5 attribute. For example:

```
<a title="Download PDF" download="Sample.PDF" href="data:application/pdf;base64,%PDFCONTENT%">Click here to download</a>
```

About the printing PDF in Firefox: if you use the latest Firefox then it may use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) based viewer. Try to [switch to Adobe Reader plugin](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-built-pdf-viewer-and-use-another-viewer) instead as it still works best when need to view or print PDF.